# What is the proper way of using keywords of Admob in Flutter ? No real ads

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, admob

Altough my AdMob account is verified I am not getting any kind of ads even on released app.

Can anyone check my code and tell me if anywhere I am doing something wrong ? When I write `BannerAd.tesUnitId` instead of my real banner ad unit Id it shows some pseudo banner ads, so I guess there are no errors while implementing it. But, when I write my admob banner ad unit ID I get the messages I am not using targetInfo, would it be the case?

```
W/flutter (26177): onAdFailedToLoad: 3
I/flutter (26177): BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad
```

I would appreciate any help.

```
MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
);

BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
  adUnitId: "[here is my unit ID]",
  size: AdSize.smartBanner,
  //targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
  },
);

void initState() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: "[my admob ID]");
    myBanner..load()..show();
    super.initState();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is nothing wrong with your code. Your implementation is absolutely correct.

This happen because of lack of advertisement in Google.

I highly recommend to add target info to increase fill ratio because Google can easily display advertisement according to your information.

Error Code 3 : ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL
Description (Dev Docs Link) : The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

Why is  it Happening : Advertisers can target specific regions, platforms and user profiles based on business relevance, which can sometimes result in lower availability of Ads for a particular region or user profile. Error code suggests that the implementation is correct, and that the Ad Request was not filled because of lack of availability of a suitable Ad at that particular instant of time when an Ad Request was sent from the app.

Policy related restrictions on certain Apps or Ad Units will also lead to Error Code 3 being returned in response to Ad Requests.

Read more: https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

First Test Ads on the Test Device After your ads are visible on the test devices it will be visible on other devices too. Also check for your dns or Adblockers

https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/quick-start

here is google official guide for flutter Admob look into it

Comment: link not working